# wp Advance custom field - default choice depending on choice from another array

Tags: php, wordpress

My users can select different kind of site headers, and there are three selects that combine with each other.

I have a "Full" and "Centered" header - when they select "Full" I want my other select to be "Gradient", but when they change to "Centered" I want the default to be "Light solid". I'm really not experienced in wordpress and advanced custom fields.

Here's my code:

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_post-style',
        'title' => __('Post style', 'crisp'),
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_56a21897616b9',
                'label' => __('Top image style', 'crisp'),
                'name' => 'crisp_top_image',
                'type' => 'select',
                'required' => 1,
                'choices' => array (
                    'centered' => 'Centered image',
                    'full' => 'Full screen image',
                ),
                'default_value' => 'centered',
                'allow_null' => 0,
                'multiple' => 0,
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'field_56a218f9616ba',
                'label' => __('Header text background', 'crisp'),
                'name' => 'crisp_text_bg',
                'type' => 'select',
                'required' => 1,
                'choices' => array (
                    'light-solid' => 'Light solid background',
                    'light-transparent' => 'Transparent light backgrund',
                    'dark-transparent' => 'Transparent dark background',
                    'gradient' => 'Gradient background',
                    'none' => 'No background',
                ),
                'default_value' => 'gradient', // I want this one to change
                'allow_null' => 0,
                'multiple' => 0,
            ),
```

Can I make a function that alters this? If so, how do I get these arrays?